# MainWindow.Closing event not always raised in Silverlight 4 OOB app

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I've made a rather complex Silverlight 4 out-of-browser application. One of my main view models adds an event handler to the Application.Current.MainWindow.Closing event.
This works fine when the application is initially run. It is able to cancel the close operation.

However, *sometimes* after performing operations like showing and closing a ChildWindow, the MainWindow's Closing event is no longer calling my handler.

In the debugger, I added a watch to the MainWindow's underlying closing event delegate. It's not null before showing the ChildWindow. Then *sometimes* after the ChildWindow is closed the delegate is null. This is explains why my handler is not called any more. But why is this delegate getting nulled? And why is it only happening occasionally?
My application is not unbinding my event handler at any point.

This is the delegate I'm watching:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.m_closingEvent
```

Other stuff: I'm using Caliburn Micro

Comment: Sounds like a really good question.  First diagnositic I would use is create a simple OOB app (no caliburn etc) that simply opens and closes ChildWindows and swaps out RootVisuals to see if a simple repro can be created.

Comment: Ok, I have the same problem - as soon as I don't open/close the ChildWindow then the Closing event fires. Sometimes if I have the debugger attached it will also fire but not always. I tried the ApplicationWrapper below with no joy. Any suggestions?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. We have a large silverlight application running OOB.

For some reason the m_ClosingEvent was nulled after running for a while. I have not been able to find the cause of this issue but I think it may have something to do with us changing the root visual or all the child windows we show.

I´m using a class ApplicationWrapper.

```
public class ApplicationWrapper : IApplicationWrapper
{
  public void Initialize()
  {
    HookCloseEvent(true);
  }
  private void HookCloseEvent(bool hook)
  {
    if (hook && IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
    {
      Application.Current.MainWindow.Closing += OnClosing;
    }
    else
    {
      if (IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
      {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Closing -= OnClosing;
      }
    }
  }
  private void OnClosing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
  {
    InvokeClosing(e);
  }

... etc.. 
}
```

And the InvokeClosing method was never called. But when I changed it to

```
public class ApplicationWrapper : IApplicationWrapper 
{
  private Window _mainWindow;

  public void Initialize()
  {
    if(IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
    {
      _mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    }
    HookCloseEvent(true);
  }

  private void HookCloseEvent(bool hook)
  {
    if (hook && IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
    {
      _mainWindow.Closing += OnClosing;
    }
    else
    {
      if (IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
      {
        _mainWindow.Closing -= OnClosing;
      }
    }
  }

  private void OnClosing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
  {
    InvokeClosing(e);
  }

... etc... 
}
```

The m_ClosingEvent isn´t nulled.

So, try to just store the "initial" MainWindow in a field and check if that solves your problem.

Comment: I just tried this out and it seems to work! I will need to test on a few more machines to be sure, but it looks like you've solved it (and solved it simply!) Thank you you so much! I'll mark this as the answer and award your bounty soon.

Comment: I can't get this to work - where is the IApplicationWrapper class? It does not seem to be in Silverlight 4 and Google returns very little information on it?

Comment: There is not IApplicationWrapper interface in the framework. Its just an interface I wrote to enable dependencyinjection and unittesting for whatever is dependent on the applicationwrapper. But if you dont care about that you could just copy the application wrapper and Initialize it from you mainwindow I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hooking to the event, why not register a service instead? Create a class that implements IApplicationService and IApplicationLifetimeAware. The latter gives you an "onexiting" and "onexited" pair of events. You place the service in the application by pointing to it in a section called  in your App.xaml. I've used this for many projects and never had an issue with the exiting methods not being called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need the ability to cancel the exiting event (after prompting the user). That interface doesn't seem to provide an option for that.

Comment: +1, Not because its an answer to the problem at hand but because its just a tidy thing to do.  Also its just too easy to forget App lifetime objects so its nice to be reminded, you don't have to do everything in App Start and Exit.

Comment: +1, been looking for a neat solution that that problem. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, however, I also can't Cancel the Exit service - I can't find the OnExiting events that you mention so there's no way to cancel?

Comment: Ok, I played around with this on the weekend - here is my conclusion: IApplicationWrapper does not exist in my project libraries so that does not help. There's no OnExiting event in the IApplicationService so I can't cancel my exit using this method. My MainWindow closing event never fires. All I want to do is ask the user if they are sure when they click on the Window Close button when running OOB... there seems to be no way to do that still....

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after pulling out my hair and many false starts [I finally found the answer](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/185664/424174.aspx) - it seems to be a known bug with the Closing event, OOB and ChildWindows open/closes...

The trick is to store a static reference to the Main Window:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //you have to store this to work around the bug
    //http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/185664/424174.aspx
    _mainWindow = App.GetApp.MainWindow;

    App.GetApp.MainWindow.Closing += (s, e1) =>
    {
        if (UIUtilities.ShowMessage("Would you like to exit AMT Mobile?", "Exit Application", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) != MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            e1.Cancel = true;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rodney but I don''t see where you use _mainWindow? Unfortunately the links to silverlight.net work not anymore.

Comment: Also App.GetApp.MainWindow; GetApp is unknown?